# Apple wallet pass not shown notification message

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, passbook, notificationcenter

I created an eventTicket pass for apple wallet. All working fine, passes added to Wallet, devices are register and I am able to push notification and update the passes successfully. The only problem I've got it's not showing the change message neither adding the notification to the Notification Center.

This are an example of the passes pass.json:

**First pass sent**

```
{
  "formatVersion" : 1,
  "passTypeIdentifier": "pass.code.paq.test",
  "serialNumber": "14",
  "teamIdentifier": "TE4545WNZ9",
  "webServiceURL": "https://testdomain/applewallet/deviceservice/",
  "authenticationToken": "2344e35c-c348-345c-945b-32bce234bc12",
  "organizationName" : "Test"
  "description" : "testpass",
  "foregroundColor" : "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
  "eventTicket": {
    "primaryFields": [
      {
        "key": "member",
        "label": "MEMBER NAME",
        "value": "John Smith"
      }
    ],
    "secondaryFields": [
      {
        "key": "level",
        "label": "LEVEL",
        "value": "Black",
        "changeMessage": "Your Level just change to %@"
      }
    ],
    "auxiliaryFields": [
      {
        "key": "membershipNumber",
        "label": "NUMBER",
        "value": "3324234234234234"
      },
      {
        "key": "memberSince",
        "label": "MEMBER SINCE",
        "value": "2016-08-22"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Updated pass**

```
{
  "formatVersion" : 1,
  "passTypeIdentifier": "pass.code.paq.test",
  "serialNumber": "14",
  "teamIdentifier": "TE4545WNZ9",
  "webServiceURL": "https://testdomain/applewallet/deviceservice/",
  "authenticationToken": "2344e35c-c348-345c-945b-32bce234bc12",
  "organizationName" : "Test"
  "description" : "testpass",
  "foregroundColor" : "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
  "eventTicket": {
    "primaryFields": [
      {
        "key": "member",
        "label": "MEMBER NAME",
        "value": "John Smith"
      }
    ],
    "secondaryFields": [
      {
        "key": "level",
        "label": "LEVEL",
        "value": "Blue",
        "changeMessage": "Your Level just change to %@"
      }
    ],
    "auxiliaryFields": [
      {
        "key": "membershipNumber",
        "label": "NUMBER",
        "value": "3324234234234234"
      },
      {
        "key": "memberSince",
        "label": "MEMBER SINCE",
        "value": "2016-08-22"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Am I missing something??

Comment: I can'r see any obvious problems with your pass.json.  One obvious thing to check would be your phone config.  Do you have updates turned on for the pass, and notifications turned on for Wallet?  Also would help if you could post details of your test device and the version of iOS.

Comment: I tested both on Iphone 6 plus (ios 9.3.4) and Iphone 5 (ios 8.4. This one has Passbook instead of Wallet). Both have 'Allow notifications' Enabled for Wallet/Passbook and the passes enabled 'Automatic Updates'. Both update the pass, but I still don't get notify when this happens, neither notification on the notification center

Comment: Can you post the pass.json? For before and changed pass? Maybe able to see something in the bundle.

Comment: They are the ones posted on the original question, I just changed ids, tokens, etc. They are both identical but the value of the secondaryField that changed.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the .pkpass bundles.  Have you decompiled and ensured that the pass.json inside is correct?

Comment: Could you see something wrong with it @PassKit ?

Comment: I don't have access to these files

Comment: Sorry, my bad. This link should work: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxjvA0NYJzoMR3dNcnExak4xcG8&usp=sharing

Comment: There is nothing wrong with these files.  If I install one and then the other, then I receive the change message as expected.  I would check the phone configuration for notifications, and also double check that your push is being received and the device is requesting the updated pass.

Comment: But if the pass is being updated on my environment, the wallet contains the second one is on wallet after I push, that means push and update request are working, right? Thank you for your help @PassKit, much appreciated.

Comment: Yes - if the pass in the wallet changes without any intervention from the user then it means that the push is working.

Comment: Thank you very much